# Wordpress require to enter ftp login/pass

Tags: wordpress

I want to update plugins and WordPress. When I press the refresh button, wordpress requires to enter FTP username and password. When I enter the correct data, the script runs. Unfortunately, the white window appears, and WordPress and plugins not updated. I think there is a problem because there are no some permissions to the folder or on the process. I tried to put the rights to the folder, but the problem persists.

Regards, Denis.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Wordpress does not have a lot of time to update all plugins through FTP.

Put temporarily chmod 0777 to /wp-content and /wp-content/plugins. If WP has rights to edit files in this directories it will update plugins files directly, without using FTP. It can be faster.